# Unusual case in MPI_Recv! The last three elements of received array are wrong?

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

## Updated version

*I found out the part which caused to problem which was previously explained below. I also wanted to share the situation with you. I realized that there is only an absurd mistake I did. However, I wonder how this problem occurs even if I made a big mistake as following;*

I have a struct definition as following;

```
#define FP_TYPE double

/* Struct : Nonzero */
struct nonzero{
    int row_index;
    int column_index;
    FP_TYPE value;
};

/* Typedef struct Nonzero */
typedef struct nonzero Nonzero;
```

I have an array of Nonzeros to be distributed the among processors from a master processor. To do that, I just created a new data type MY_MPI_NONZERO as following,

```
#define MPI_FP_TYPE MPI_FLOAT

/**
 * Declare an MPI data type for
 *      + Nonzero Structure
 * */
const int number_of_items = 3;
int block_lengths[3] = {1, 1, 1};
MPI_Datatype data_types[3] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_FP_TYPE};
MPI_Datatype MY_MPI_NONZERO;
MPI_Aint offsets[3];

/* Set Offset Array */
offsets[0] = offsetof(Nonzero, row_index);
offsets[1] = offsetof(Nonzero, column_index);
offsets[2] = offsetof(Nonzero, value);

/* Create the Point Struct and Commit it */
MPI_Type_create_struct(number_of_items, block_lengths,
        offsets, data_types, &MY_MPI_NONZERO);
MPI_Type_commit(&MY_MPI_NONZERO);
```

Eventually, I distributed different arrays of Nonzeros as explained in the older version of the question below detailedly.

Now, the problem was based on the definition of Nonzero structure and Nonzero data type. As you may realized, I mistakenly used MPI_FLOAT when defining Nonzero data type, whereas used double in Nonzero structure for value member of Nonzero struct. This may be a problem, but values are read from a file in only a simple format, like 1.2, 2.0 ... How this can be caused to a big problem like the last some parts of the sent arrays is wrong? In addition, why only last three elements are wrong?

## Old version of the question

I just want master processor to send a different array to other processors. Each processor knows what the size of incoming array is, and also master knows how many elements it will send to others. I have a scatter function for an array, which keeps the number of total elements will be sent to each processor as below,

```
/* Scatter number of nonzeros per each proc */
MPI_Scatter(no_dist_nonzero, 1, MPI_INT,
        &my_no_nonzeros, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

/* Define nonzero array */
if ( my_rank != MASTER )
{
    nonzero = (Nonzero *) malloc(
            sizeof(Nonzero) * my_no_nonzeros);
}


/**
 * Declare an MPI data type for
 *      + Nonzero Structure
 * */
const int number_of_items = 3;
int block_lengths[3] = {1, 1, 1};
MPI_Datatype data_types[3] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_FP_TYPE};
MPI_Datatype MY_MPI_NONZERO;
MPI_Aint offsets[3];

/* Set Offset Array */
offsets[0] = offsetof(Nonzero, row_index);
offsets[1] = offsetof(Nonzero, column_index);
offsets[2] = offsetof(Nonzero, value);

/* Create the Point Struct and Commit it */
MPI_Type_create_struct(number_of_items, block_lengths,
        offsets, data_types, &MY_MPI_NONZERO);
MPI_Type_commit(&MY_MPI_NONZERO);
```

Also the remain part of the code as following;

```
if ( my_rank == MASTER )
{
    int mem_index = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < comm_size; i++ )
    {
        if ( i != MASTER )
        {
            /* Calculate count and size */
            int sub_count = no_dist_nonzero[i];
            int sub_size = sub_count * sizeof(Nonzero);
            Nonzero *sub_nonzero =
                    (Nonzero *) malloc(sub_size);

            /* Divide nonzero array */
            mem_index += no_dist_nonzero[i-1];
            memcpy(sub_nonzero,
                    nonzero + mem_index, sub_size);


            /* Send nonzeros */
            MPI_Send(sub_nonzero, sub_count,
                    MPI_NONZERO, i,
                    MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
}else
{
    MPI_Recv(nonzero, my_no_nonzeros, MPI_NONZERO,
            MASTER, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    for ( i = 0; i < my_no_nonzeros; i ++ )
    {
        printf("P[%d] : nonzero[%d] = %.2f\t(%d,%d)\n",
                my_rank, i, nonzero[i].value,
                nonzero[i].row_index, nonzero[i].column_index);
    }
}
```

It is like a broadcast but with different number of elements for each processor. Now, when I print out the received elements, **only the last three elements** of each received array in each processor are wrong, like 0, or different kind of numbers. A sample scenario I created for explanation with 4 processors and except master(rank = 0) processor, remain processors keep 10, 11 and 11 elements in their arrays as following,

Print statement represents the next line;

**Processor[rank] : receivedNonzero[index] = nonzero.value  (nonzero.row, nonzero.column)**

```
P[1] : nonzero[0] = 4.00    (5,0)
P[1] : nonzero[1] = 1.00    (5,7)
P[1] : nonzero[2] = 1.00    (6,1)
P[1] : nonzero[3] = 9.00    (6,4)
P[1] : nonzero[4] = 1.00    (7,2)
P[1] : nonzero[5] = 8.00    (7,7)
P[1] : nonzero[6] = 3.00    (8,3)
P[1] : nonzero[7] = 0.00    (8,5)
P[1] : nonzero[8] = 0.00    (1,-2147483648)
P[1] : nonzero[9] = 0.00    (180366288,32731)

P[2] : nonzero[0] = 9.00    (10,2)
P[2] : nonzero[1] = 2.00    (10,3)
P[2] : nonzero[2] = 2.00    (11,5)
P[2] : nonzero[3] = 2.00    (12,0)
P[2] : nonzero[4] = 2.00    (12,7)
P[2] : nonzero[5] = 2.00    (13,1)
P[2] : nonzero[6] = 1.00    (13,3)
P[2] : nonzero[7] = 6.00    (13,5)
P[2] : nonzero[8] = 0.00    (14,32715)
P[2] : nonzero[9] = 0.00    (1215315376,32715)
P[2] : nonzero[10] = 0.00   (1215319296,32715)

P[3] : nonzero[0] = 4.00    (15,0)
P[3] : nonzero[1] = 2.00    (15,4)
P[3] : nonzero[2] = 2.00    (16,6)
P[3] : nonzero[3] = 3.00    (17,0)
P[3] : nonzero[4] = 7.00    (17,3)
P[3] : nonzero[5] = 9.00    (18,1)
P[3] : nonzero[6] = 3.00    (18,4)
P[3] : nonzero[7] = 3.00    (18,7)
P[3] : nonzero[8] = 1141143300351626597783743016932944640301310822732232512436170973423802137351962278027655782681814493455862954554635505069706412465354938627437900810355923222434815569775088619100027795823768424096546808505779224664332855111823098875222717104128.00 (19,1645150208)
P[3] : nonzero[9] = 0.00    (825110830,302186544)
P[3] : nonzero[10] = 0.00   (1,8108)
```

Is there any idea what is going wrong in this scenario? Even if I printed out the **sub_nonzero array before** MPI_Send() to check whether there was a mistake in splitting array into sub arrays, however; there was nothing wrong...

Comment: To identify if the eror is in scatter or in send/rcv, first set everything to zero and see if the last entries are still wrong. If not: check scatter; else check send/rcv.

Comment: ...and we need to see mroe of your code: types, input, how arrays are filled.

Comment: What are you even using? `MPI_Scatter` or `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv`? Why both? Please provide a [mcve] (read that page carefully!).

Comment: @Zulan Try to see what I am doing on my code... I am using those for different goals, which can not be combined in that scenario

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I check all those things as I emphasized in my question. Everthing is OK before MPI_Send(). After and before send operation, I printed out the array will be sent, and it was OK. But, after the receive the last three elements all the time are wrong. I am updating question to show you other parts.

Comment: Do MPI error checking. Must all be `MPI_SUCCESS `.

Comment: My vague guess is that you try to build your own `MPI_Gatherv`, but I can't guess what `Nonzero` is or how you build up `MPI_NONZERO`.

Comment: @Zulan I updated the questions. See the part where I created a new data type for MPI. You can infer that Nonzero is a struct, as having 3 members.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I did error checking. Each of them is success..

Comment: We cannot check your code if you do not provide for example the structure `Nonzero` definition. Please post an [mcve]!

Comment: @Zulan Thanks. After your comment, I checked out the Nonzero structure and just solved the problem which was based on the data type I used for value member in Nonzero structure and in new MPI data type I created. Now, I am updating the question to show you how this error occurs, since I really wonder how this kind of small change can cause this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this leads to an error, is that the data sizes of `float` / `double` do not match. With this wrong information, MPI writes data to the wrong places in memory.

This is basically undefined behavior and anything may happen, including nasal demons. The reason why - in practice - only the tailend of the data is wrong, lies in the following. MPI actually doesn't necessarily care for the individual meaning of the bytes. Since the data is contiguous, it just cares about the overall size - so it simply transmit too little data. You interpret the data the same way at the sender and receiver, the part that was transmitted looks just fine.

I can't help but mention how this is a prime example how important it is to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Please see my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42121393/7496118