# MPI_Irecv does not properly receive the data sent by MPI_Send

Tags: c, mpi

I have a 1D matrix data as `Q_send_matrix`. In each iteration, each processor updates its `Q_send_matrix` and sends it to the previous processor(`rank-1`), whereas it receives a newly updated matrix as `Q_recv_matrix` from the next processor(`rank+1`). For instance, in an iteration, `Proc[0]` updates its `Q_send_matrix` and sends it to `Proc[3]`, whereas it receives `Q_recv_matrix` from `Proc[1]`. As you may estimated, it is like a ring communication. Please see the code below **after** my explanation below of the code.

```
        MPI_Request request;
        MPI_Status status;

        // All the elements of Q_send and Q_recv buffers 
        // are set to 1.0 initially. Each processor
        // updates its Q_send buffer to prepare it
        // to be sent below.(above part is big, so it
        // is not added here...)

        /**
         * Transfer Q matrix blocks among processors
         *      + Each processor sends the Q matrix
         *  + to the previous processor while receives
         *  + the Q matrix from the next processor
         *      + It is like a ring communication
         * */


        /* Receive Q matrix with MPI_Irecv */
        source = (my_rank+1)%comm_size;
        recv_count = no_col_per_proc[source]*input_k;

        MPI_Irecv(Q_recv_matrix, recv_count,
                MPI_FP_TYPE, source,
                0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                &request);


        /* Send Q matrix */
        dest = (my_rank-1+comm_size)%comm_size;
        send_count = no_col_per_proc[my_rank]*input_k;

        MPI_Send(Q_send_matrix, send_count,
                MPI_FP_TYPE, dest,
                0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        /* Wait status */
        // MPI_Wait(request, status);

        /* Barrier */
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        /* Print Q send and receive matrices */
        for( j = 0; j < send_count; j ++ )
        {
            printf("P[%d] sends Q_send[%d] to P[%d] = %.2f\n",
                    my_rank, j, dest, Q_send_matrix[j]);
        }

        for( j = 0; j < recv_count; j ++ )
        {
            printf("P[%d] receives Q_recv[%d] from P[%d] = %.2f\n",
                    my_rank, j, source, Q_recv_matrix[j]);
        }
```

I want to do this communication as a syncronous. However, it is not possible with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` due to the deadlock based on their blocking feature. Hence, I used `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Send` together with an `MPI_Wait`. However, it did not finish, all the processors were waiting. So, I put an `MPI_Barrier` instead of `MPI_Wait` to make them syncronous, and solved the wait issue of the processors, so they finished their work. However, it did not work properly. Some outputs of the code as following are wrong. Each processor sends the correct data, and there is no problem on the sending side. On the other hand, there is no change on the received data buffer. It means that in some processors the initial value of the received buffer remains even if received a data from one of the other processors as following.

```
P[0] sends Q_send[0] to P[3] = -2.12
P[0] sends Q_send[1] to P[3] = -2.12
P[0] sends Q_send[2] to P[3] = 4.12
P[0] sends Q_send[3] to P[3] = 4.12
P[0] receives Q_recv[0] from P[1] = 1.00
P[0] receives Q_recv[1] from P[1] = 1.00
P[0] receives Q_recv[2] from P[1] = 1.00
P[0] receives Q_recv[3] from P[1] = 1.00

P[1] sends Q_send[0] to P[0] = -2.12
P[1] sends Q_send[1] to P[0] = -2.12
P[1] sends Q_send[2] to P[0] = 0.38
P[1] sends Q_send[3] to P[0] = 0.38
P[1] receives Q_recv[0] from P[2] = 1.00
P[1] receives Q_recv[1] from P[2] = 1.00
P[1] receives Q_recv[2] from P[2] = 1.00
P[1] receives Q_recv[3] from P[2] = 1.00

P[2] sends Q_send[0] to P[1] = 1.00
P[2] sends Q_send[1] to P[1] = 1.00
P[2] sends Q_send[2] to P[1] = -24.03
P[2] sends Q_send[3] to P[1] = -24.03
P[2] receives Q_recv[0] from P[3] = 1.00
P[2] receives Q_recv[1] from P[3] = 1.00
P[2] receives Q_recv[2] from P[3] = 1.00
P[2] receives Q_recv[3] from P[3] = 1.00

P[3] sends Q_send[0] to P[2] = 7.95
P[3] sends Q_send[1] to P[2] = 7.95
P[3] sends Q_send[2] to P[2] = 0.38
P[3] sends Q_send[3] to P[2] = 0.38
P[3] receives Q_recv[0] from P[0] = -2.12
P[3] receives Q_recv[1] from P[0] = -2.12
P[3] receives Q_recv[2] from P[0] = 4.12
P[3] receives Q_recv[3] from P[0] = 4.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** finish an `MPI_Wait` or a successful `MPI_Test` before accessing the data from `MPI_Irecv`. You cannot replace that with a barrier.

For a ring-communication, consider using `MPI_Sendrecv`. It can be simpler than using asynchronous communication.

Comment: Did you realize that I used MPI_Wait in the code, as commented now. It did not work. All the processors were waiting when I used only a MPI_Wait...?

Comment: I realize that you have a **commented out** `MPI_Wait` in your code. My answer addresses your immediate question and recommends a generally alternative way to address this without manual nonblocking communication. If you wish to further investigate why `MPI_Wait` is not completing in your case. Please post a [mcve] with that. Note that your code is generally bogus, like `&request[my_rank]` won't compile. This leads me to believe that the code does not represent your actual code.

Comment: No man! To solve the problem, I changed request variable with a request array as offered from a guy... So, I just forgot to update that part. Now, I updated it. By the way, how you can think this code as a bogus, there is an output printed by my code .... Anyway, from this scenario, without a minimal complete example what is your suggestion?

Comment: @kundilcas, how does this code even work given that all receives specify tag 0 and the sends tag `my_rank`, which is non-zero except for one rank?

Comment: @HristoIliev You are right. It was also from the previous version of the code as explained in my previous comment. I just also updated it now.